# Increase /home partition with unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04, gparted

I would like to increase my `/home` partition but I can't find right manipulation to do it (I know I need to use gparted live cd) but when I try yo extend the `/home` partition, there is no disk space available.

Can someone help me and tell me the right manipulation to increase the `/home` partition ?

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of gparted.  Along with the answer, if you have a partition blocking the un-aallocated space you'd have to delete that so that your home partition is adjacent to it.  Be particular for any partition you may delete.  Also be sure to back up important data for any partition you may delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to move your partitions around so that the unallocated space is immediately after your /home partition; only then can you expand it.

Note that moving partitions is a risky and lengthy process, because the data must be physically moved on the disk. Back up your important data, and grab a good book.

Comment: We're not supposed to +1 in comments, but +1 for mentioning that it's risky and lengthy.